# React open weather api - creating a five day forecast

Tags: reactjs, api, openweathermap

I've developing a five day forecast weather app using OpenWeatherAPI with React.

I want to be able to show a five day forecast rather than every 3 hours forcast (As per attached)[image]

I've read the docs of the OpenWeather API but the only thing i was able to find was to add a `cnt` value to your url string in my app.js file which i have done but still im not able to target it.

Here is my app.js

```
import React from 'react';
import CitySelector from './components/CitySelector';
import './App.css';
import {Container} from 'react-bootstrap';
import UseFetch from './hooks/UseFetch';
import {API_KEY, API_BASE_URL} from './apis/config'
import WeatherList from './components/WeatherList';

const App = () => {
  const {data, error, isLoading, setUrl} = UseFetch();

  const getContent = () => {
    if(error) return <h2>Error when fetching: {error}</h2>
    if(!data && isLoading) return <h2>LOADING...</h2>
    if(!data) return null;
    return <WeatherList weathers={data.list} />
  };

  return (
    <Container className="App">
      <CitySelector onSearch={(city) => setUrl(`${API_BASE_URL}/data/2.5/forecast?q=${city}&cnt=5&appid=${API_KEY}&units=metric`)} />

      {/* conditionally render  */}
      {getContent()}
    </Container>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

As per the [docs](https://openweathermap.org/forecast16), add `daily` to your url: `api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast/daily`

Comment: this API does not have a `q` parameter. It has `lat` and `lon`

Comment: you can convert `city` to `lat` and `lon` using https://openweathermap.org/api/geocoding-api